Как заставить второй монитор показывать НЕ расширенный рабочий стол?
Есть небольшой монитор, который подключен через HDMI. Сейчас дисплей подключен как "Расширение экрана". Как можно его подключить отдельно? чтобы курсор мыши не переходил на второй экран?

чтобы курсор мыши не переходил на второй экран - а что должно быть на втором экране тогда?

как минимум стоит добавить os

Нужно указать операционную систему. Чего вы пытаетесь добиться вообще? В Windows есть два режима работы: клонирование и расширение рабочего стола. Вы постоянно теряете курсор? Увеличьте размер указателя. Есть функция поиска курсора - нажать и удерживать Ctrl. Настройте вертикальное расположение экранов, тогда вы не сможете перемещать курсор в бок.

"чтобы курсор мыши не переходил на второй экран" - а как будете пользоваться???

.. и опечатку в "Разрешение экрана" тоже стоит истправить.

И все же, почему поправив вопрос вы не указали основное -- какая ОС?  И еще одно, вы хотите использовать этот дополнительный монитор только для вывода информации некоторыми приложениями?

@avp, метка [tag:windows]

@Grundy, спасибо, теперь обратил внимание на добавленную метку. Можно успокоиться, не моя тема

Использовал когда-то давно для ограничения курсора данную свободную программу
https://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
